# How to prepare 1/2" subfloor for hardwood flooring?

Tags: subfloor, hardwood-floor

My house had carpets over 5/8 particle board that was sitting on top of 1/2 plywood subfloors. I've removed the particle board and was thinking of installing 5/8 OSB before putting down 3/4 hardwood flooring since I've read that 1/2 subfloors are not thick enough for hardwood. First question, is that the right approach? Is 5/8 absolutely necessary or can I get away with something thinner and less costly?

Comment: Please see [ask]. Only ask one question per post. [Proper way to install double-layer of subfloor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/39039/proper-way-to-install-double-layer-of-subfloor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern homes are often built with 3/4" OSB subfloors. This is the minimum standard, in my opinion, and it's what you need to achieve. Solid hardwood flooring adds considerable stiffness itself, *but only where it runs perpendicular to the joists*. That may not be the case everywhere, so you need to get to that minimum standard.

I would probably add 1/2" OSB or CDX plywood. You don't need a smooth surface, so you don't need to pay for B-grade plywood, for example. Just adding 1/4" material wouldn't achieve the same level of stiffness that a single 3/4" subfloor would (unless you were to completely bond the two layers with adhesive). 3/8" plywood would also probably suffice.

I suggest that you run whatever plan you choose by your flooring installer. Any warranty will depend on a proper subfloor, and some more scrupulous installers won't even do the job if they're not happy with what you have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you suggest using screws to attach the second layer to the joists?

Comment: Fixing the second layer using glue and screws would be better, quieter and stiffer.

Comment: Screws or ring-shank pneumatically-driven nails, along with construction adhesive.